# Node.js is not a good option for file uploads (and all event-loop based languages) - is that true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, sails.js

It's said that using Node.js is not advisable for file uploads, because it blocks the IO loop till completion, so I tried to stream-upload many concurrent files, and I found out that Sails.js (wrapper around express and node)  uploads chunks from the first,second, third ... to the N uploader, and then back to the first uploader again to get the next chunk in a round-robin fashion, the result is: all file uploads complete almost at the same time in a way similar to uploading one big file which size equals the aggregate sizes of the concurrent uploaded files.

I finally came to a conclusion that high hit-rate file upload systems shall not be designed by a language that employs the IO event loop technology, instead each connected uploading client shall have its own thread on the server to achieve the proper separation between different uploads as well as a liner relationship between server's memory size and the number of clients.

Did I reach a correct conclusion here, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: *It's said that using Node.js is not advisable for file uploads* - Where did you hear that? Any link?

Comment: I read that before, ironically I can't find it again, but I found the other way around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981624/will-node-js-get-blocked-when-processing-large-file-uploads , so this mean I'm wrong about this

Comment: @AleksandrM, but I still my questions stands: I experience slowness when concurrently upload files I don't face when I use thread based systems, still I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion that

> each connected uploading client shall have its own thread on the server to achieve the proper separation between different uploads

is not right since every thread in a process consumes resources for memory management, thread switching and so on. Thus building a *hit-rate file upload* in a threaded environment with unbounded threads will not scale. When using a stream based upload solution in node.js the memory footprint and performance of your application should be quite competitive compared to other languages/platforms.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried your suggestion with stream uploads and wrote my conclusion in the question as well

Comment: ```the result is: all file uploads complete almost at the same time in a way similar to uploading one big file which size equals the aggregate sizes of the concurrent uploaded files.```

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion can't be further from the truth. Event loop based concurrency is extremely efficient for I/O tasks like file uploads (also happening at the same time). Event loop is blocked just for the time when your code runs - event callbacks, like connection ready, some more data is available etc. In your code you just do very quick things like saying what you want to do with data, where it should go etc. Filling up buffers and I/O transfers is handled by OS kernel. On modern computer you can do something like 60000 (+/- 50000) concurrent transfers like that while keeping your code running normally.

Comment: Does this mean the node.js forks the file upload to anther thread to keep the main thread free to receive new requests?

Comment: If what I say is right, what makes it different from Apache style uploads (a thread per connection)

Comment: Also, how would you explain the slowness I experience when I concurrently upload files in a way I don't experience in thread based systems

Comment: Maybe you're using "sync" methods?

Comment: No, it doesn't fork anything, OS kernel deals with doing multiple things at the same time.

The difference between "a thread per connection" is that you don't need to create threads per connection. If you want to upload 60000 files at the same time it's going to be slow if you have that many threads - your kernel will need to switch between all the time and this switching is expensive. With event loop there's just one thread to deal with, no context switches, network buffers are filled up and your event loop wakes up when notified when buffers are ready.